# How can I find the Windows firewall profile for a given IP address range?

Tags: networking, ip, adapter, firewall, profile

Given the IP address or address range I want to automatically find the corresponding network adapter name. The final goal is to move the network adapter from the public to the private firewall profile. The tools I can use are reading/writing the Windows registry and Windows command line tools.

I found that firewall profiles are listed in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles. However the network adapter names used there do not correspond to any name I can find associated to the IP addres.

I didn't find any match using ipconfig and netsh advfirewall, e.g. there is no match between the names shown with "netsh advfirewall monitor show currentprofile" and "ipconfig /all".

Also the powershell cmdlet Set-NetConnectionProfile was not helpful as it requires the name, not the IP range.

Example: while ipconfig shows the network interface name for a given IP address as "Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2", I need to somehow figure out the network name as "Vodafone-1234" as shown in the firewall profile.

Answer (score 0):

I think Windows firewall profiles are not by default tied to any interface or IP address, they are tied to the type of network the machine is connected to, domain, private, or public. A domain joined machine knows it's connected to the domain. When you connect to a new network for the first time, Windows asks if you want to consider it a private or a public network, then treats it that way, including assigning that firewall profile, regardless of which interface is used to connect to it.

According this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ics/frequently-asked-questions, it's possible to manually associate an interface with a firewall profile, maybe that will help.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I suppose that my understanding of profiles is incomplete. Still I want to do in a program something similar to what is suggested in the link you provided. When a program opens a network connection, it starts with a remote IP address (and a port, not relevant here), and finally the firewall decides which profile has to be applied. And my goal is to configure the firewall so that it uses the private profile for that connection.